# How can I save a docker image without having enough storage on my main drive?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nvidia-jetson

**My problem:**

I'm trying to save a Jetson TX2 docker image that's about 8GB. The OS and other files+OS are taking up around 21GB meaning I only have about 3GB of storage on the machine. I have already pruned old images and containers, and cannot delete or free up any more space. Because of this I've tried saving the docker image to an USB stick.

However, when I try to build the docker file I get the error:

```
*Error response from daemon: write /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-export-50xxxxx/layer.tar: no space left on device*
```

Even though I am trying to save the docker image to an USB with enough space, Docker seems to build the whole file first using the /var/lib/docker/tmp/ folder and then wants to move it to the USB. However there simply isn't enough space on the device. Because of this I keep getting the error listed above.

**My question:**

Is there any way to save a docker image without using my main drive as intermediary storage? I can ssh into the Jetson and have an USB/SD card with sufficient capacity. If there is another solution that would solve my problem that would be great to hear too.

Comment: I am not an expert in Linux but probably you can mount your flash drive to `/var/lib/docker/tmp/`..

Answer (score 0):

Mount the USB drive on the system and then use the -o flag of docker export to export the image.

So with an example USB drive mounted on /mnt/usb, use ....

```
docker export -o /mnt/usb <CONTAINER ID>
```